# The web server at http://srvr1" does not appear to have MS SP Foundation installed Error when opening the site collection in SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, site-collection

I have taken a site collection's content db back up from one development server and restored it in another development server and mounted on a new web application and site collection.But when I try to open the site collection in the sharepoint designer,I am getting the error "The web server at http://srvr1" does not appear to have MS SP Foundation installed".I am stuck with this and did not understand why this error appears since I am able to open the site in the IE.

Comment: try to open the site in browser(IE) then from their click on edit in designer...check if it works

Comment: am getting the errors: unable to open the web site possible causes:1 . the web server may not have sh server installed.2.web sever may be temp. out of service. 3.if you are connecting through a proxy server the proxy settings may be incorrect 4.an error may have occured in the web server.

Comment: add that site into the trsuted zone of IE, clear the IE cache and restart the browser...now try it.

Comment: @Waqas, Thanks for the lightning reply.Will try the same and update here.